# Hourly average of minute data with no date

Tags: r, date, time, average

I'm looking to get the hourly average of minutely data. However, the data does not contain the date - just the time. The questions and solutions I've read seem to rely on using the date.

A snippet of the data:

```
     Time photon activity food light
 11:51:39  18077       46    1     0
 11:52:39  22938       37    1     0
 11:53:39  24895       15    1     0
 11:54:39  24311        2    1     0
 11:55:39  21018        3    1     0
 11:56:39  21143       12    1     0
```

There is some data missing too so taking the average of every 60 observations would not work.

I've tried to add an artificial date to the data but as you can imagine this has simply created 24 averages which span the entire dataset.

```
tt <- strptime(paste("2015-07-21", data$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
data <- cbind2(tt, data[,3:6])

hr.means <- aggregate(data["activity"], 
                  list(hour = cut(data$x, breaks="hour")), 
                  mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I'm stuck on the best way to attack this.
Thanks.

Comment: So you have multiple days worth of data measured every minute or so? You will need to add an identifier for when each new day starts if that is the case. Then you can do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368796/aggregating-minutes-to-hour-demand-r/22369242

Comment: If your data spans multiple days, how do you know when a particular time is on a different day to another time? are your rows in date-time-order or something? and you never skip more than a day? if I have a row "13:00" followed by a row "14:00" is the second row guaranteed to be on the same day as the first, or could it be say a day in the future (25 hours later)?

Comment: My guess(tm): It's ordered and you need to add one day for each diff(time) < 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a reproducible example here. I made a data.frame with the first column time, the second column any quantity you want to average.

```
   Time Whatever
1 10:00       17
2 10:02      119
3 10:04       98
4 10:06       94
5 10:08      219
6 10:10       71
```

With stringr we can extract the hour as a numeric and the rest is just arithmetic.

```
library(stringr)
data = data.frame(Time=c("10:00", "10:02", "10:04", "10:06", "10:08", "10:10", "10:12", "10:14", 
"10:16", "10:18", "10:20", "10:22", "10:24", "10:26", "10:28", 
"10:30", "10:32", "10:34", "10:36", "10:38", "10:40", "10:42", 
"10:44", "10:46", "10:48", "10:50", "10:52", "10:54", "10:56", 
"10:58", "11:00", "11:01", "11:02", "11:03", "11:04", "11:05", "11:06", 
"11:07", "11:08", "11:09", "11:10", "11:11", "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", 
"11:15", "11:16", "11:17", "11:18", "11:19", "11:20", "11:21", 
"11:22", "11:23", "11:24", "11:25", "11:26", "11:27", "11:28", 
"11:29", "11:30", "11:31", "11:32", "11:33", "11:34", "11:35", 
"11:36", "11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", "11:41", "11:42", 
"11:43", "11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", "11:48", "11:49", 
"11:50", "11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", "11:55", "11:56", 
"11:57", "11:58", "11:59", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", 
"15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:20", "16:40", "16:50")
,Whatever=c(17, 119, 98, 94, 219, 71, 38, 31, 8, 48, 139, 48, 90, 2, 40, 
130, 164, 66, 14, 218, 13, 31, 177, 55, 74, 75, 17, 167, 0, 21, 
56, 132, 138, 183, 94, 81, 1, 85, 25, 148, NA, 129, 25, 139, 
84, 15, 41, 226, 79, 215, 26, 218, 23, 119, 102, 31, 195, 73, 
50, 148, 29, 21, 154, 73, 114, 44, 80, 80, 86, 48, 52, 44, 106, 
124, 43, 43, 174, 47, 214, 202, 111, 13, 96, 153, 59, 83, 20, 
134, 163, 4, 59, 147, 71, 119, 113, 188, 19, 195, NA, 101), stringsAsFactors=F)
thour = as.numeric(str_extract(data$Time,'\\d{2}(?=:)'))
x = c(0,which(diff(thour) != 0),length(thour))
n = length(x)-1
interval = list()
for (i in 1:n) interval[[i]] = c(x[i]+1,x[i+1],thour[x[i+1]])
u1 = sapply(interval,function(j) j[3])
u2 = sapply(interval,function(j) mean(data$Whatever[j[1]:j[2]],na.rm=T))
data.frame(hour=u1,average=u2)
```

Finally you will get something like. It also avoid the problem of averaging data from the same hour on different day.

```
  hour   average
1   10  76.13333
2   11  93.13559
3   15 116.16667
4   16 105.00000
```

Comment: Apologies, I'll try and give a reproducible example next time. That being said, this works perfect. Thank you very much for the help.